# Rails + Activerecord: How to show records with "ranking ASC" first, then show the rest of the records "name ASC"?

Tags: activerecord

I have 2 columns in my awards table: ranking (integer) and name (string). I want to create a scope that shows all the records with the ranking column filled in in ascending order (1, 2, 3...), and then the rest of the records that don't have a ranking to show by name ascending (a, b, c) so it would look like this:

1. ranking: 1, name: "zz"
2. ranking: 2, name: "aaa"
3. ranking: nil, name: "bbbb"
4. ranking: nil, name: "ccc"
5. ranking: nil, name: "ddd"
6. etc...

This doesn't seem to work: `scope :book_form_sort_order, -> { order("ranking ASC, name ASC").group(:ranking) }`

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :book_form_sort_order, -> { order("ranking IS NULL, ranking ASC, name ASC") }
```

Comment: anyone care to explain why this answer works? I don't get it. Wouldn't that be putting all the ranking == nil records first? why does it behave the way I want it to?